# Undo "git reset --merge"

Tags: git, merge, reset, undo

I just did:

```
git reset --merge
```

and I lost my latest modifications to some files, how do I undo this last action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can look at your reflog to find the commit at wich you were before:

```
git reflog
```

Once you find your previous commit, copy the sha-1 hash and

```
git reset <commit sha-1> --hard
```

Although, if what you lose was uncommitted modifications, well then they're lost.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this terrible advice to run `git reset --merge`  while trying to resolve VSCode induced unwanted merge. Very weird state of repo, and as the question mentions, `git reset --merge`  wipes out uncommitted changes, yet git does NOT warn about this to happen.

Anyway, if you're in VSCode with local file history on, you can somewhat recover from this by opening files with lost changes and reverting them to last saved state. This works in case you remember where you had uncommitted changes... if you don't remember however, you're totally out of luck I guess.

[image]